# How to declare variables in Android (Kotlin) using Google code style?

Tags: kotlin, coding-style

I started to build the app in Kotlin and I want to know how to correctly initialize variables. For example in Java it was like:

```
 private TextView mSomeTextView;
```

And then we call findViewById in some methods. But in Kotlin I can't just write something like that, I need to:

```
private val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.text)
```

I write it under onCreate as I used to. Question: is it right place for it? If no -- where and how should I do it?

Comment: Do you want a member property (field) or a private variable? That looks fine for a private variable.

Comment: @PaulHicks Say I have a few Views in my Activity. I declare them, make them private, somewhere initialize and then do something with them. That is what I want to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use [`lateinit`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties):

```
private lateinit var textView: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text)
}
```